# How do I install LibreOffice 6 in Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice 6.0 has been released. How can I install LibreOffice 6 in Ubuntu? What is the official PPA?

Comment: Voting to leave closed. The PPA, and manual download links provided in the answers are stil valid, and lists LibreOffice 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use their [installation method](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/?type=deb-x86&version=6.0.0&lang=en-US) from source.

The official PPAs at the moment are at 5.4.4 since 6.0 is still in "testing". The people from Libreoffice will release a PPA when "testing" is finished.

---

PPA with the "latest" release can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-prereleases) and in:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

But I do not see 6 in there yet. 5.4.4 is the highest.

Comment: As of 29 Jan 2018, the `libreoffice-prereleases` PPA includes `1:6.0.0~rc3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo2`. :) The release of 6.0 was announced on the [Document Foundation blog](https://blog.documentfoundation.org/blog/2018/01/31/libreoffice-6/) today.

Comment: It doesn't work on Ubuntu 12

Comment: Ofcourse not. Ubuntu 12 is end of life.