# Error running Libreoffice 6.0.5. Did ubuntu 18.04 fix itself after I looked up the version number?

Tags: libreoffice

I followed these instructions:
[How do I install LibreOffice 6 in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000061/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-6-in-ubuntu)

In Terminal, I typed libreoffice. This error appeared:

> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libuno_sal.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Then the Software Updater opened and I ran an update that fixed the error.

In Terminal, I typed libreoffice and the application ran. 
Simultaneously, this error appeared:

> func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:file=xmlsec.c:line=188:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=19:invalid
>   version:mode=abi compatible;expected minor version=2;real minor
>   version=2;expected subminor version=25;real subminor version=26

At first, I thought there was something wrong, but since it mentioned something about a version, I went back to terminal and typed:

> libreoffice --version

LibreOffice 6.0.5.2 00m0(Build:2)

Next, commands

> soffice

The application opened without the error. I closed the application

Next, command

> libreoffice

The application opened without the error.

Did Ubuntu fix itself after looking up the version number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i stumbled upon this one:
https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118373

The first part of your question about why the error message changed:
Yes after you did a software update, some previously missing dependencies may have been declared, and thus the library libuno_sal.so.3 was installed.

The second part is a bit more mystery:

My assumption is, that Libreoffice starting from some point in time to at least version 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 was compiled with libxmlsec1 1.2.26 but in Ubuntu 18.04 the current version of libxmlsec1 is still 1.2.25-1build1.

Libreoffice does not load that library on every call, and if your terminal command does not load an ODS for example, you dont see this message.

If you try to open a Calc sheet for example, i assume you will still see this message, until the devs of libreoffice push a solution, to silence the warning, or solve the dependency issue.