# Open a file based on its modification date

Tags: libreoffice

I know how to open a LibreOffice writer file from the command line. I need to open the most recently modified file in the directory specified in path. It is an .odt file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `zsh` in your terminal, you can use its *glob qualifiers* to select the youngest `.odt` file (by **m**odification time):

```
soffice path/to/dir/*.odt(om[1])
```

To use the zsh features from another shell, you could do

```
zsh -c 'soffice path/to/dir/*.odt(om[1])'
```

Comment: I left out a crucial piece of information. The most recent file has spaces so it appear in the directory as 'file name.odt'. Also, I do not use zsh. I use bash. I tried a number of variations with no success so far.

Comment: @Rogo the above method should work for any legal file name (including those with spaces and even newlines)

Comment: Installed zsh and it worked!! Thanks

Comment: Although it worked and I am glad for that, there were two lines of error messages in the terminal after the execution. I can ignore them but prefer to improve my code/understanding. Is there a place I can go to decipher this? Here are the msgs func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:file=xmlsec.c:line=188:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=19:invalid version:mode=abi compatible;expected minor version=2;real minor version=2;expected subminor version=25;real subminor version=26

Comment: @Rogo that would be a message from LibreOffice itself, rather than from the shell command. See for example [Error running Libreoffice 6.0.5. Did ubuntu 18.04 fix itself after I looked up the version number?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108733/178692)

Comment: you helped me on this some months ago and it works fine for I have used it a lot since. But I made it into a script so I could just execute ./tasksheet and it works like a macro. Now I can't find the script. I doubt I put it anywhere other than wherever linux defaults to. Can you guess where it is? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as the file name does not contain returns or other very strange characters, you can use `ls -ct` to sort files most recently modified on top. You want to see only Libreoffice documents. You can use `grep` to filter these. The first, which you can obtain with `head -n 1`, will be the one you will want to open. You will open a file with the associated application using `xdg-open`. If the shell variable `mypath` contains the path to where your files reside, then following command will open the most recently modified `.odt` document.

```
xdg-open "$mypath"/"$((cd "$mypath"; ls -ct) | grep -i '.odt$' | head -n 1)"
```