# Libre offce open latest file date from command line

Tags: libreoffice

Here is my present CLI to open a file in Libre Office

libreoffice /

which works just fine.
However, rather than naming the file to open I want to open the most recently modified .odt file in the directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a file based on its modification date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365371/open-a-file-based-on-its-modification-date) Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: Sorry - I just realized I was signed up twice in one place. Will delete the duplicate